# server namespace for app-engine javascript client

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Normally my endpoints have an android/iOS client. I am now trying to work with a javascript client. Looking at the provided [git example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/base.js), I see a number of namespace stuff (lines 9-19). Why are those important? Say my api exists at `my-endpoints.appspot.com`, do I have to do the namespace thing? How?

Also does anyone have a more comprehensive example they don't mind sharing? Something that more fully exercises the full client api https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good example is Romin Irani's tutorials: https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-4-37ea3aac7948

Note however that Google recently advised to use the promise mode of the Google API Client Library for JavaScript. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises#using-promises and [How to call App Engine Endpoints with the JavaScript library in promises mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528364/how-to-call-app-engine-endpoints-with-the-javascript-library-in-promises-mode)

Answer (score 1):

The ['namespace thing'](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/base.js#L10) is not necessary. You should be free write in the style that you like by [loading your code as they do in the example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.html#L5) and [making a no-argument initialiser](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.html#L78) that calls your code, which is passed to the [API client here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.html#L82). It seems that a `gapi` global is initialised after the google api client is loaded but before your code is run. This allows your endpoint [to be accessed](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/base.js#L95).