# How to call GAE Endpoints from WebApplication

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

Hi I am developing an Web application(Using Java for business logic). and I have stored my Application data in Google Appengine datastore.

Can anyone help me here how can i call GAE cloud Endpoinds from Web Application...

Comment: do you know that tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/js/

Comment: No @MichaelMeyer that's why only asked

Comment: ok, then just tell me if the tutorial were helpful

Comment: Yeah @MichaelMeyer Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A classical way to connect a Web Application (i.e. an HTML front-end) to an App Engine back-end is by using the Google JavaScript client library https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Romin Irani has nice tutorials on this method, see https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1-b571ad6c7cd2#.sbsqvfu3n and in particular Part 4 https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-4-37ea3aac7948#.ivyo2i4pb

There is also a free MOOC on Udacity which covers Endpoints: https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-scalable-apps-in-java--ud859

Note that Google recently advised to use the promise mode of the Google API Client Library for JavaScript. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises#using-promises and [How to call App Engine Endpoints with the JavaScript library in promises mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528364/how-to-call-app-engine-endpoints-with-the-javascript-library-in-promises-mode). Neither the Udacity examples nor Romin Irani's tutorials use promises, but the "older" way, which still works correctly.